# Docker-Compose is ignoring parts of the dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running `docker-compose` 2.6.0 and `docker` 19.03.5 on Unraid.

I am having weird issues where docker-compose just completely ignores statements in Dockerfiles, while docker does not.

I have one image that uses the official nginx image, and [that one definitely has a cmd](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nginx/library/nginx/latest/images/sha256-3536d368b898eef291fb1f6d184a95f8bc1a6f863c48457395aab859fda354d1?context=explore), yet docker-compose does not find a command. It attempts to create the container, and on startup says `Error response from daemon: No command specified`.

I have an old custom Dockerfile I used for postgres stuff which looks a little something like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.12

# Build arguments
## The database user name
ARG DBUSER
## The user's password
ARG DBPASS
## The database name
ARG DBNAME

# Forward the args to the container
ENV DBUSER=${DBUSER}
ENV DBPASS=${DBPASS}
ENV DBNAME=${DBNAME}
# Read only DB user
ENV DBROUSER=${DBROUSER}

ENV PGDATA "/var/lib/postgresql"

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add postgresql postgresql-contrib

RUN mkdir -p /run/postgresql && chmod a+w /run/postgresql

ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
USER postgres

VOLUME $PGDATA

CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5432
```

And docker-compose just ignores the largest chunk of it. If I do a `docker build`, it runs through 17 steps, sets all environment variables and the cmd. However, if I do a `docker-compose build postgres` (which is the service name in my compose file), it does 5 steps, ignoring all ENV as well as the CMD.

```
root@Tower:/mnt/user/docker# docker-compose build --no-cache  postgres
[+] Building 17.9s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                              1.7s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                           1.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.12                                                                                                                                 1.1s
 => CACHED [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.12@sha256:c75ac27b49326926b803b9ed43bf088bc220d22556de1bc5f72d742c91398f69                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                              1.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [2/5] RUN apk update && apk upgrade &&     apk add postgresql postgresql-contrib                                                                                                           5.4s
 => [3/5] RUN mkdir -p /run/postgresql && chmod a+w /run/postgresql                                                                                                                            2.9s 
 => [4/5] ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                                                     0.9s 
 => [5/5] RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                                                          2.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                         3.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                        2.8s 
 => => writing image sha256:e4e29a8ec77b77e6344fec29331666103de24a02e546e2183b9c32a88450745d                                                                                                   0.1s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker_postgres                                                                                                                                             0.1s
```

What is going on? What am I doing wrong? I was able to "fix" (which I shouldn't have to imho) the nginx image by adding a `command` to the service in my `docker-compose.yaml` (the same one the actual Dockerfile I linked above uses), but I shouldn't have to double-maintain environment variables and commands to use docker-compose. It hasn't been doing that historically, but it started recently, specifically on that machine.

Please let me know if I can provide you with any further input (or output of the system) that would help investigate the issue.

Comment: Should you have an `ENTRYPOINT` rather than a `CMD`? Also, I thought (from memory) the syntax is `COPY` not `ADD`

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I am not excluding the possibility, but would it syntactically be wrong if `docker build` properly builds it, but `docker-compose build` does not?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if it's an old version of the Syntax and docker-compose expects a newer version... I could be completely left of field but it's just my initial thoughts because it looks weird to me

Comment: @ScottishTapWater If you're not splitting the command into either command/arguments or wrapper/command, then it's functionally almost identical to use only `ENTRYPOINT` or only `CMD`.  There is no requirement to have an `ENTRYPOINT`.  If I only need one part, I prefer `CMD` since it's easier to override and easier to adapt to the wrapper/command pattern.